# Python graphing of time series

Tags: python, linux, graphing

I have a project that will requiring graphing data (with Python).  rrdtool seems to be almost exactly what I need- except it only supports 1 second resolution and my data points are much closer together.

GNUPlot looks like a beast.  I've not dug into it yet, but in a cursory glance, it seems more tailored to graphing expressions and not something to be learned quickly.

Is there another (hopefully relatively easy to use) graphing system tailored or easily adaptable to graphing time series?  If there is nothing better then GNUplot, I will start digging into it- I just wanted to be sure there is nothing else I should consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made use of [PyX](http://pyx.sourceforge.net/) before.  It's served my purposes well when I needed to graph various data.

There's also [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), which is a very popular Python plotting library.

Comment: matplot looks promising! PyX, from the website doesn't output image files? (png, jpg, gif etc)? I didn't specify before, but I will need to put these graphs on the web.

Comment: I often use matplotlib by going to their [gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html), finding an image that looks like the one I want to make, and copying the code they provide that produced the image.

Comment: tMC: Matplotlib/Pylab does output png or pdf (and more, depending upon the plotting backend). `pylab.plot(xcoords, ycoords); pylab.savefig('myimage.png')`.

Comment: @tmc:  It does PDF and EPS files, which aren't like PNG, JPEG, GIF.  If you wanted those exportable types, then I would say matplotlib would be the better choice.

Answer (score 3):

You don't fully specify what you are looking for, but here is a quick cut and paste-able example that shows some of the plotting abilities of `matplotlib`. The example also saves the image as a png and pdf (rasterized and vectorized respectively):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# Create some sample "time-series" data
N = 200
T = np.linspace(0, 5, N)
Y1 = T**2 - T*np.cos(T*5) + np.random.random(N)
Y2 = T**2 - T*np.sin(T*5) + np.random.random(N)

pargs = {"lw":5, "alpha":.6}

plt.plot(T,Y1, 'r',**pargs)
plt.plot(T,Y2, 'b', **pargs)

skip = 30
plt.scatter(T[::skip],Y2[::skip], color='k', s=200, alpha=.6)

plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("money")
plt.axis('tight')

# Save as a png and a pdf
plt.savefig("example.png")
plt.savefig("example.pdf")

plt.show()
```

[image]